# ADB installs apps for all users. How to force it to install to main user only?

Tags: adb, installation, multi-user

I have a LineageOS 17.1 system on Pocophone F1, unrooted. When I install an apk through USB using adb, adb not run as root, the app is installed both on my main admin user and on a secondary user on my phone. How do I force adb to only install the app for my main user only?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mention the specific user as an argument for which the package is to be installed. Example:

```
adb install --user USER_ID YOUR_APK
adb shell pm install --user USER_ID YOUR_APK    # alternative command
```

`USER_ID` for main/primary user is always `0`.

Sidenote: in case of difficulty with an adb command, simply enter `adb` as the sole command. It would list help section.

Comment: Note to see what the UID of a user is, use `adb shell pm list users`